# transfer method not working in bank program

Tags: java, oop, debugging, switch-statement

I am currently having some trouble with the transfer method of my java bank problem. For whatever reason, when I transfer money from one account to another, it does not actually transfer. I thought that this may be because the cases did not have lowercase statements (eg. case "checking" as opposed to case "Checking", but this did not fix the error. It did, however, keep it from printing the default case saying that "You entered an invalid number". Here is the code:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CustomerDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            Customer customer = new Customer(System.in);
            int accountChoice; // show which account needs to be chosen.
            String cusSel; //for customer selection.
            double money;
            do
                {
                    System.out.println("main menu to be selected: " );
                    System.out.println("1.deposit " );
                    System.out.println("2.withdraw " );
                    System.out.println("3.transfer " );
                    System.out.println("4.print balance " );
                    System.out.println("q.quit " );
                    cusSel=in.next();
                    switch(cusSel.charAt(0))
                    {
                        case '1':
                            System.out.println("please select account: " );
                            System.out.println("1. Checking" );
                            System.out.println("2. Saving " );
                            accountChoice=in.nextInt();
                            if((accountChoice==1)||(accountChoice==2))
                                {
                                    System.out.println("please imput the deposit amount: " );
                                    money=in.nextDouble();
                                    if(accountChoice==1)
                                        {
                                            customer.deposit(money, "Checking");
                                        }
                                    else if(accountChoice==2)
                                        {
                                            customer.deposit(money, "Saving");
                                        }
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                    System.out.println("invalid choice. your choice does not exsist");
                                    break;
                                }
                            break;

                        case '2':

                            System.out.println("Please select account: " );
                            System.out.println("1. Checking" );
                            System.out.println("2. Saving " );

                            accountChoice=in.nextInt();
                            if((accountChoice==1)||(accountChoice==2))
                                {
                                    System.out.println("please input the withdraw amount: " );

                                    money=in.nextDouble();


                                    if(accountChoice==1)
                                        {
                                            customer.withdraw(money, "Checking");
                                        }
                                    else if(accountChoice==2)
                                        {
                                            customer.withdraw(money, "Saving");
                                        }
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                    System.out.println("invalid choice. your choice does not exsist");
                                    break;
                                }
                            break;

                        case '3':

                            System.out.println("please select an account to transfer from: " );
                            System.out.println("1. Checking" );
                            System.out.println("2. Saving " );

                            accountChoice=in.nextInt();
                            if((accountChoice==1)||(accountChoice==2))
                                {
                                    System.out.println("please input the transfer amount: " );

                                    money=in.nextDouble();

                                    if(accountChoice==1)
                                        {
                                            customer.transfer(money, "saving");
                                        }
                                    else if(accountChoice==2)
                                        {
                                            customer.transfer(money, "checking");
                                        }
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                    System.out.println("invalid choice. your choice does not exsist");
                                    break;
                                }
                            break;

                        case '4':
                            customer.printBalance();
                            break;
                        case 'q':
                            System.out.println("transaction complete, please have a nice day");
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("invalid choice.");

                    }

                } while (cusSel.charAt(0)!= 'q' && cusSel.charAt(0)!= 'Q');

        }
    private void getAccountChoice(int accountChoice) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}

class Customer
{
    //two objects/ saving and checking
    Account Saving = new Account();
    Account Checking = new Account();
    public Customer(InputStream in)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
    boolean deposit(double amount, String acc)
        {
            double currentBalanceChecking, currentBalanceSaving;// this currentBalence is subtracted from and account.
            boolean retVal = false;
            switch (acc)
            {
                case "Checking": case "checking":
                    if(amount >=0)
                        {
                            currentBalanceChecking = this.Checking.deposit(amount);
                            retVal = true;
                        }
                    break;
                case "Saving": case "saving": 
                    if(amount >=0)
                        {
                            currentBalanceSaving = this.Saving.deposit(amount);
                            retVal = true;
                        }
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("You entered an invalid number.");
            }
            return retVal;
        }
    boolean withdraw(double amount, String acc)
        {
            double currentBalanceChecking, currentBalanceSaving;// this currentBalence is subtracted from and account.
            boolean retVal = false;
            switch (acc)
            {
                case "Checking": case "checking":
                    if(amount <=Checking.getBalance())
                        {
                            currentBalanceChecking = this.Checking.withdraw(amount);
                            retVal = true;
                        }
                    break;
                case "Saving": case "saving": 
                    if(amount <=Saving.getBalance())
                        {
                            currentBalanceSaving = this.Saving.withdraw(amount);
                            retVal = true;
                        }
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("You entered an invalid number.");
            }
            return retVal;
        }
    boolean transfer(double amount, String acc)
        {
            double currentBalanceChecking, currentBalanceSaving;// this currentBalence is subtracted from and account.
            boolean retVal = false;

            switch (acc)
            {
                case "Checking": case "checking":
                    if(amount <=Checking.getBalance())
                        {
                            currentBalanceChecking = this.Checking.withdraw(amount);
                            currentBalanceSaving = this.Saving.deposit(amount);
                            retVal = true;
                        }
                    break;
                case "Saving": case "saving": 
                    if(amount <=Saving.getBalance())
                        {
                            currentBalanceSaving = this.Saving.withdraw(amount);
                            currentBalanceChecking = this.Checking.deposit(amount);
                            retVal = true;
                        }
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("You entered an invalid number.");
            }
            return retVal;
        }
    void printBalance()
        {
            System.out.println("The checking balance is $" + Checking.getBalance());
            System.out.println("The saving balance is $" + Saving.getBalance());
        }
}


class Account
{
    double balance;
    //the constructor tells the customer that there are zero dollars in the account.
    Account()
    {
        balance = 0;
    }
    //deposit money
    double deposit( double depAmount )
        {
            balance= balance + depAmount;//balance+ = depAmount
            return balance;
        }
    double withdraw( double withAmount )
        {
            balance= balance - withAmount;//balance- = withAmount
            return balance;
        }

    double getBalance()
        {
            return balance;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Account class starts out with $0. Your transfer methods don't provide output for when the amount to be transferred is greater than the account's balance.

Comment: Yes, but when I run the program, I deposit some money into it, and when I do the printbalance, it is right. However, the transfers do not work at all.

Comment: You prompt `please select an account to transfer from:` but you actually transfer money out of the other account.

Comment: I cannot believe that it was that simple. Thanks for your help!